# C++ GET Array Error

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I am having a problem with pieces[] at Copy Constructor and Equal Oparator. i am trying to get pieces like code and month_year but it drops me an error saying 'class machine' has no member named 'get'

```
#include <iostream> 

#include <string>



using namespace std; 

class machine {


public:


void set_code(string my_code){

code=my_code;
}

void set_month_year(int my_month_year){

month_year=my_month_year;
}

void set_pieces(int *my_pieces){

for(int i=0;i<25;i++)

pieces[i]=my_pieces[i];

}

string get_code(void){

return code;

}

int get_month_year(void){

return month_year;




int get_pieces_i(int i){

return  pieces[i];

}
```

//Default Constructor

```
machine(){

code.erase();

month_year=0;

for(int i=0;i<25;i++)

pieces[i]=0;

}
```

//Destructor

```
~machine(){}


void print_data(void){

cout << "Code= " << code << endl;

cout << "Month Year " << month_year << endl;

}
void print_pieces(void){

for(int i=0;i<25;i++)

cout << pieces[i] << endl;

}


machine(string my_code, int my_month_year,int *my_pieces){

code=my_code;

month_year=my_month_year;

for(int i=0;i<25;i++)

pieces[i]=my_pieces[i];

}
```

//Copy Constructor

```
machine  (machine& a)

{

code=a.get_code();

month_year=a.get_month_year();

pieces=a.get.pieces_i();

}
```

//Equal Operator

```
void  operator = (machine & a)

{

code=a.get_code();

month_year=a.get_month_year();

pieces=a.get_pieces_i();


}
```

// month & year

```
int get_month(void) {

return month_year/100;

}

int get_year(void) {

return month_year%100;

}
```

//return 0 & 1

```
int ckeck_code(void) {

int counter=0;

for (int i=0;i<25;i++) {

if (pieces [i] <10) {

counter=counter+1;

}

if (counter<5)

return 0;

else

return 1;

}

}


private:

string code;

int month_year;

int pieces[25];


};


int main(void){







    return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both copy constructor and assignment operator (yes, it's called *assignment operator*, not *equal* operator) should have their parameter of type `const machine&` instead of `machine&`.

On the `get_*` functions, they should be declared as constant member functions. That is,

```
string get_code(void) const {
    return code;
}

int get_month_year(void) const {
    return month_year;
}

int get_pieces_i(int i) const {
    return pieces[i];
}
```

Furthermore, the copy constructor and assignment operator should handle `pieces` like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    pieces[i] = a.get_pieces_i(i);
```

to match the getters' prototype.

Comment: now i am having error saying..
error: passing 'const machine' as 'this' argument of std::string machine::get_code()
and same for month_year

Comment: @user3225577 Edited for the const issue.

Comment: good const errors fixed.. but i still have the problem saying, no matching function for call to machine::get_pieces_i() or get.pieces_i()..

Comment: @user3225577 Edited again for `get_pieces_i()`.

Comment: after 20 hours i'm finally happy